# Percorrer um for até uma data limite em php

Tags: php, mysql

Pretendo que só insira linhas até à data que eu defino, mesmo que o array tenha datas superiores à data definida.

Estou a tentar desta forma:

```
$dia = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( 2021-12-01 10:00:00 ));
```

A esta variável vou somar 14 dias várias vezes, desta forma:

```
$teste = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+14 days', strtotime($dia)));
$teste1 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+14 days', strtotime($teste)));
$teste2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+14 days', strtotime($teste1)));
$teste3 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+14 days', strtotime($teste2)));
$teste4 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+14 days', strtotime($teste3)));
$teste5 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+14 days', strtotime($teste4)));

$arr=array($dia, $teste, $teste1, $teste2, $teste3, $teste4, $teste5);
```

Defino a data limite nesta variável:

```
$fim = '2021-12-31 23:59:59';
```

Agora, pretendo que percorra o `for` até à data que defini na variável `fim`.
Estou a fazer desta forma:

```
for ($i = $arr; $i <= $fim; $i++) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO PlanifPreve(title, empresa, equipamento, nome, color, start, Observacao, Perio, Perio1, Perio2, colaborador) values ('$title', '$empresa', '$equipamento', '$nome', '$color', '$arr[$i]', '$Observacao', '$Perio', '$Perio1', '$Perio2', '$Colaborador')";
    
    $i++;
}
```

Neste caso só, pode inserir 3 linhas em base de dados, porque despois as datas que vem no array com o nome `arr` já são superiores à data que defini na variável `fim`.

Podem ajudar?

Comment: O `for` está errado: `$i = $arr` (`i` recebe o array? deveria ser `0`, pois ele é a posição dentro do array). O mesmo para `$i <= $fim`, não é o índice que deve ser comparado com a data e sim o elemento na posição `i`. Enfim, se quer que a data seja menor que o fim, coloque isso na condição também: `for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr) && $arr[$i] < $fim; $i++) { usar $arr[$i] }`

Comment: E também não precisa do `$i++` dentro do `for`, pois isso já é feito no próprio bloco de incremento: https://ideone.com/wpUsxK

Comment: @hkotsubo Obrigado, é mesmo isso. Já testei e funcionou